# How merge duplicate data using google app script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to merge duplicate data using an app script. I got this script from here. It seems it worked, but somehow it merged the wrong cell. It seems it's not able to read my data correctly.

[image: !enter image description here]

Can someone check the code and let me help? here is the code

Here is the code:

```
function mergepkw() {
  const columns = [3, 3]; 
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; 

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const [,,,,,,...values] = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  values[0]
  .map((_, i) => values.map(e => e[i]))
  .forEach((col, i) => {
    if (!columns.includes(i + 1)) return;
    let temp = {};
    col.forEach((row, j) => {
      if (row === col[j + 1] && !(row in temp)) {
        temp[row] = j;
      } else if (row != col[j + 1] && row in temp) {
        sheet.getRange(temp[row] + 2, i + 1, (j - temp[row]) + 1, 1).merge();
        temp = {};
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the code is near unreadable especially for a newbie like me. Look at this script I created below instead using simple nested while loop.

```
function merge() {
  // merges column C
  const column = 3;
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; 
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  const keywordGroup = sheet.getRange(1, column, lastRow, 1).getValues().flat();

  var i = 0;
  while (i < keywordGroup.length) {
    // while iterating whole column, have another iterator 
    // that will offset how many rows are needed to be merged
    var offset = 1;
    // iterate offset if the next row is the same and still within the length of column
    while (i + offset < keywordGroup.length && keywordGroup[i] == keywordGroup[i + offset])
      offset++;
    // if offset got iterated, merge those rows
    if(offset > 1) 
      sheet.getRange(i + 1, column, offset, 1).merge();
    // iterate main iterator based from how many cells you merge
    i += offset;
  }
}
```

[image]

Word of advice, don't just blindly copy another code without understanding it. Especially for codes you copied above, not a newbie friendly code. If you are a newbie like me, I do recommend trying it yourself first. You can learn much faster that way instead of copy pasting someone's code. A simple nested while loop should solve the problem you have above.